# Mock a bigquery cursor in python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pytest

I'm trying to test a function which iterates over a big query cursor. When I retrieve the value of the cursor in VS code using debug I get `<google.api_core.page_iterator.HTTPIterator object at 0x7fc51f481be0>` and a bunch of different metadata listed, but I need the shape of the cursor, so I can make a mock of the data and test the function.

The function I'm trying to test is:

```
def table_list():

#Get BigQuery Credentials
project_id=os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))
client=bigquery.Client(credentials = credentials, project = project_id)

n=[]
d=[]
for t in client.list_tables('trending_CL'):
    n.append(t.table_id)
    d.append(t.created)
idxs=np.argsort(d)[::-1]
tables=np.array(n)[idxs]
tabledd=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in tables]
return tables,tabledd
```

So I need to mock the value returned from client.list_tables('trending_CL'), but can't get a sample of the shape of this cursor to make a data array or similar to pass to the for loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you need the shape of the cursor? if you know the logic that is supposed to happen with the returned data, then just mock out the data. from a cursory glance it seems you need some objects with a `table_id` and `created` attribute

Comment: @gold_cy when I create a class (i.e. class TableData) with those properties I get the error `TypeError: 'TableData' object is not iterable`

Comment: share your test code, otherwise we can't help you pinpoint errors